# Compare 2 folders and move 'not duplicates' to a new folder

Tags: music, music.app

Folder 1(210GB) contains the contents from Folder 2(198GB) plus some extra files.

All files are music.

Looking for a way to find out what is in Folder 1 that isn't in Folder 2.

Hope that makes sense.

Answer (score 3):

There is a fleet of software that does this, for example [beyond compare](https://www.scootersoftware.com/index.php). It is not a free Software, but it has a free trial and for doing it once it should be fine.

You can also use `diff` in the terminal to search for those files like this:

```
diff --brief -r dir1/ dir2/
```

This will give you an output similar to this one:

```
Only in dir1/dir11/dir111: file4
Only in dir2/: file2
Only in dir1/: file3
```

You can then use cut and sed to get the missing files and their paths:

```
| cut -c 9- | sed 's/\/: /\//g' | sed 's/: /\//g'
```

And then you can use xargs and cp to copy the files like this:

```
xargs -I{} cp "{}" dir3
```

So the whole line would be

```
diff --brief -r dir1/ dir2/ | \
    cut -c 9- | sed 's/\/: /\//g' | sed 's/: /\//g' | \
    xargs -I{} cp "{}" dir3
```

Just make sure to replace dir1 and dir2 with directories that you want to search and dir3 with the output directory.

If you want to keep the folder structure for the copied files use `ditto` instead of cp like this:

```
diff --brief -r dir1/ dir2/ | \
    cut -c 9- | sed 's/\/: /\//g' | sed 's/: /\//g' | \
    xargs -I{} ditto "{}" dir3
```

Answer (score -1):

If you're happy doing move the folders to do processing of them on Windows, MindGems Fast Duplicate File Finder (FDFF) will do the job. No affiliaton.

Being able to treat one folder as read-only to be compared against other folders is the crucial feature that FFDF can help you with. In FDFF this feature is covered by 2 features:

- "Disable folders for self-scan (compare folders)" and
- "Exclude folders from auto-check". This means that nothing is changed or removed in the read-only folder. Only the duplicate files are marked in the other folder, that is being compared within itself and with the read-only folder.

I love my Apple MacBook Air M2 as I do my Air i7 and previous Pros.  But my search for the above key feature in a native mac app has not been successful so far. They all harp on about how they are the best, but really dumb down and are superficial about their actual features. Which is a shame because then the user has to download and trial each one to discover what they might be able to do.

In your case in FDFF, you would set Folder 2 to being read-only - i.e. check both "Disable folders for self-scan (compare folders)" but leave
"Exclude folders from auto-check" box unchecked. This means that FDFF will match duplicates found in folder 2 and folder 1, but not files that are the same within folder 1 (these don't have folder 2 counterparts).

Answer (score -2):

There are multiple apps available on Appstore to find the duplicate files on Mac. Best one I would suggest is Duplicate File Finder Remover.

Comment: Does Duplicate File Finder Remover find files that are _not_ duplicates?

Comment: This app would highlight the duplicates and allow us to select and remove. This helps in cleaning.